# Detect Sitefinity widget being added to page in editor?

Tags: jquery, events, editor, jquery-events, sitefinity

I have a few MVC widgets that I have configured in my Sitefinity website. These widgets require corresponding jQuery functions to be called in order to present themselves correctly, such as a tab widget. When the widgets are added to the page in the editor they add correctly however as their accompanying jQuery functions are called on page load the functions aren't called.

Is there a global Javascript event in the Sitefinity editor that fires when a widget is added to the page? If so, I could then use the event to re-initialise my widget controls so that they look correct in the page designer.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is loaded by default in the backend. To use it on the front end you will need to follow this to add it to your .master file.

http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/gabe-sumners-blog/2011/09/01/how_to_use_jquery_and_other_javascript_libraries_in_sitefinity